# the value is null when pass data via intent

Tags: android-intent

hi every bode i have this problem in my program ...when i pass a data betwwen two intnent the value is null ...i used the toast to check the value ...

can any one find the problem

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            int GroupId ;

            GroupId= (int) listView.getItemIdAtPosition(position);


        GDialAc.putExtra("Id",GroupId);     
            startActivity(GDialAc);

        }});
```

and the next activity

final Bundle  extra = getIntent().getExtras();

```
DescBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            try {
                int GID = 0 ;
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "hi   "+extra+"hi22", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (extra != null)
            {
         GID = Integer.parseInt(extra.getString("Id"));
                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "hi   "+GID+"hi22", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }


            }catch( NumberFormatException ex ) {
            }

            }
```

thancks a lot i solved my problem by using Bundle and putExtras() in sending and getExtras in reciving not the (s) in extras

Comment: no one can help me ??

Comment: Suggest you throw a bigger net.  Add a Tag for the language you are using.  (I am not familiar with it, is it Java?)

Comment: thank you @ryyker i am just solved my problem ...this is in android using java

Comment: You are welcome.  It does help on this site to garnish as much attention as possible for questions outside mainstream technologies.  eg.  Android may not be as mainstream as say Java, so be sure to include at least Java in your tags (as well as android)